# Why is overloading not possible in C?

Tags: c++, c, oop, overloading

I know that overloading is not possible in C, and I want to know: why is overloading functions within the class and outside the class treated the same in C++?

Consider this case in C++ where the functions are declared outside the class:

```
foo()
foo(char c)
foo(int a, int b)
```

If C++ treats each function header as unique, why can't C do as well?

I think these might be the reason:

- Function overloading was introduced in C++, so it is not available in C.
- Polymorphism is an OOP concept, but C is not object-oriented.

Are there any reasons for the unavailability of function-overloading in C?

Comment: There are 3 very different questions here. Which one is most important for you?

Comment: Whenever you ask yourself why a language (any language, not just C) doesn't support a feature found in a newer language, the answer is usually the same: (1) Compare that language to older languages, not newer. (2) Make a list of features that this language introduced over the older ones. (3) Appreciate what an advancement the language represented for having those new features. (4) Realize that this is what the designers thought as well, and at some point they decided to draw a line and to call it a day.

Comment: That's why C++ was invented.

Comment: Note that early C allowed calling a function which had not been declared. With the simple linking model, this might even imply that no overloading was possible. For overloaded functions, you would have to perform overload resolution at link time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the most important reason is the lack of prior art. There are very few examples of features added to C by the standard committee which have neither been popular extensions before nor are necessary to write strictly conforming code.

There is some vaguely defined "spirit of C", the C99 rationale (V5.10) reads (page 3, emph. mine):

> Some of the facets of the spirit of C can be summarized in phrases like:
>
> - Trust the programmer.
> - Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done.
> - **Keep the language small and simple.**
> - Provide only one way to do an operation.
> - Make it fast, even if it is not guaranteed to be portable.

Further, C tries hard to stay backwards compatible with older revisions; old-style declarations, for example, have been marked obsolescent in C89 but are still part of C11. Ibid, page 2:

> **Existing code is important, existing implementations are not.** A large body of C code exists
>   of considerable commercial value. Every attempt has been made to ensure that the bulk of this
>   code will be acceptable to any implementation conforming to the Standard. The C89 Committee
>   did not want to force most programmers to modify their C programs just to have them accepted
>   by a conforming translator.

Some differences in C and C++ are at least partly caused by function overloading, for example the type of character constants:

```
int foo(int);
int foo(char);
...
    foo('x');
```

In C++, this calls `foo(char)`, but in C, the type of `'x'` is `int`, so either the result would be rather surprising, or `'x'` needed to be of type `char`, possibly breaking existing code. Further, you probably want some promotions where they make sense, e.g. if in the last example, the second declaration of `foo` wasn't given, `'x'` would be promoted to `int` and `foo(int)` was called. Such rules can become complex in detail (should `void *` be implicitly converted for function calls?). (Not a hard number, but the chapter about function overloading in the C++ standard (chapter 13) in the n3797 draft covers about 30 pages, chapter ibid. 5.2.2 about function calls is considerably longer than the corresponding C standard part.)

Pretty much every feature of C is necessary for a minimal language (well, modulo historic legacy), there is very little syntactic sugar; function overloading could be considered such (you could name your functions `foo_int` and `foo_char` etc and call the correct one explicitly).

The reasons you suggested, are circular (and thus aren't applicable): C did adopt some C++ features (e.g. function prototypes); and function overloading was introduced in C++ because C lacked it (you cannot say "It isn't part of C, because it's part of C++; and it's part of C++, because it isn't part of C"). Same goes for the second suggestion about C and OOP.

What I personally like about C is that it maps rather closely to the machine. It's often easy to see how assembler output generated from C code relates to it. The symbol names are unmangled and can be easily identified. The language is kept simple and minimal. Frankly, I don't understand what people are after when they want to see certain C++ features incorporated into C: We have C++, a language which offers those things, with the ability to write platform-specific, efficient code; why not just use it?

C11 introduced `_Generic`, which may be of interest for you.

Answer (score 8):

You may find some interesting point in [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) 7.22/25 *Type-generic math
`<tgmath.h>`* :

> The ability to overload on integer as well as floating types would
>   have been useful for some functions, for example `copysign`. Overloading
>   with different numbers of arguments would have allowed reusing names,
>   for example `remainder` for `remquo`. However, these facilities would have
>   complicated the specification; and their natural consistent use, such
>   as for a floating abs or a two-argument atan, would have introduced
>   further inconsistencies with C89 for insufficient benefit.

Also [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) Standard introduced type `_Generic` macros, that allows to some sort of overloading, in sense that different types may be handled as function-like macros arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the first and foremost reason C doesn't have function overloading is that C does not mangle function names:

Every function in C is translated to a symbol with the same name while in C++ the name gets mangled.

An example:

Take your functions:

```
void foo()
void foo(char c)
void foo(int a, int b)
```

The symbol names as mangled by the C++ code will look the following:

```
void foo() = _Z3foov
void foo(char c) = _Z3fooc
void foo(int a,int b) = _Z3fooii
```

While in C code this will translate to:

```
void foo() = foo
```

Bottom line - C++ allows name mangling, so the compiler "changes" the function names and all references to three distinct names

C does not allow name mangling at the latest standard (and I doubt this will ever change), so such a solution is just not possible.

Comment: Neither the C nor the C++ standard says anything about symbols or name mangling.

Comment: I think it's the other way around - C doesn't use name mangling because it doesn't have to support function overloading.

Comment: @T.C.: This question is not about what the standards say (the answer is easy then: C has no overloading, because the standard says so, and C++ has it for the same reason), but rather why they are written the way they are. So it's about implementations and the philosophy behind the languages; and C++ implementations usually mangle names and C implementations don't. But I agree with Anatolyg, without some explanation why name mangling might not be desired, the reasoning in this answer is circular.